# Kendo MVVM - ViewModel dentro de Outra

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, mvvm, telerik

é possível bindar uma ViewModel dentro de Outra? 
Se sim, como?

Estou precisando montar um contexto mais ou menos assim:

```
<div data-bind="visible: ViewModel_1.isVisible" />
    //....

    <div data-bind="source: ViewModel_Child1/>
         // Contexto referente ao filho 1 da viewModel
    </div>

    <div data-bind="source: ViewModel_Child2/>
         // Contexto referente ao filho 2 da viewModel
    </div>

    <div data-bind="source: ViewModel_ChildN/>
         // Contexto referente ao filho N da viewModel
    </div>
</div>
```

Seria uma estrutura mais ou menos assim da classe:

```
public Pessoa {
     public List<Contato> Contatos { get; set; }
     public List<Referencia> Referencias { get; set; }
     public List<Mensagem> Mensagens { get; set; }
}
```

E a cada Lista, tera um Grid... pq será uma tela com varias abas

```
[Pessoa] | [Contato] | [Referencia] | [Mensagem] --- // onde | no exemplo seria um separador ou aba
```

E será um registro controlado pela mesma tela, em diferente controllers...
daí o pq de para não precisar fazer uma viewModel complexa pra guardar cada `dataSource` de cada aba... queria bindar uma pra cada, mas tendo a `Pessoa` como Pai

Comment: Pode por favor passar um exemplo um pouco menos genérico? `ViewModel`s normalmente não recebem HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu encontrei a solução.

Quando tentar fazer `Nested Binds`, deve se seguir da seguinte maneira.

//....

```
<div  id="nested" data-bind="source: ViewModel_Child1/>
     // Contexto referente ao filho 1 da viewModel
</div>
```

no js:

```
var viewModelPai = kendo.Observable.observable({..});
var viewModelFilho = kendo.Observable.observable({..});

//e os binds devem ser atribuído assim

kendo.bind($("#pai").children().not("#filho"),viewModelPai);

//na diretiva acima, manda construir o bind MVVM na `div#pai` ignorando a `div#filho`
//dentro dela, permitindo assim um novo bind dentro dessa como é feito abaixo

kendo.bind($("#filho"),viewModelFilho);
```